# Can't dismiss mail view controller

Tags: swift, email, view, controller, dismiss

This code works and presents email form all filled out and sends the email just fine, just can't get it to dismiss after sending or trying to cancel.

I am sure I am missing something simple.
I also realize I have nothing in place if there is an error but at this point it works and sends email but i cant get it to dismiss

tried several suggestions I found online and there are other ways to do this but I am trying to understand why this is not working so want this way (or close) to work.... xcode 10.2.1

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: Any) {

        sendEmail()

        }

    func sendEmail() {
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients(["xxx@xx.com"])
            mail.setSubject("test  ")
            mail.setPreferredSendingEmailAddress("xxx@jxxx.com")

            present(mail, animated: true)   

        } else {
            //show failure alert
        }

        func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }
```

compiles and sends email fine just cant dismiss the controller

Comment: Don't put `didFinishWith` inside another function.

Comment: Why do you have two sendEmail methods?

Comment: Great! I knew i was missing something small.

Comment: just moved didfinish with thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All delegate methods should be in class scope , in your current code `didFinishWith` which should dimiss the mail is nested inside `sendEmail`

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: Any) { 
        sendEmail() 
    }

    func sendEmail() {
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients(["xxx@xx.com"])
            mail.setSubject("test  ")
            mail.setPreferredSendingEmailAddress("xxx@jxxx.com") 
            present(mail, animated: true)   

        } else {
            //show failure alert
        } 
    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) { 
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) 
    }
}
```